# Animate array items on position change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V9d3vN60ky3G9iSslVet?p=preview) shows an array displayed as an unordered list using `ng-repeat`.

Each item has an Up/Down button enabling to swap positions with the item above or below via a javascript `splice`.

There is also an animate directive that adds a class to each moved item: items moving up the array are highlighted green and items moving down are highlighted red.

However, the animation is buggy, I think because the directive fires `addClass` and `removeClass` on `click`. Can anybody advise if this is the case and if so, what event should replace it? I tried `$scope.$watch` unsuccessfully.

It occurred to me a better approach might be to watch the array collection, compare index changes and highlight based on whether the item index is > or < before.

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of errors. Here's a forked [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kneBm8kzVZl4c8zNuvcJ?p=preview)

```
angular.module('App').directive('animateOnChange', function($animate) {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    scope.$watch('direction', function(newVal) {
      if (newVal == 'up') {
        $animate.addClass(elem, 'change-up', function() {
          $animate.removeClass(elem, 'change-up');
        });
      }
    });
  } ; 
});
```

- The `$watch` method takes a String as its first argument
- The `element` you tried to pass to `$animate` should have been named `elem`

Going forward, remember that the `$watch` handler only fires when the `direction` is changed. So if you go 'up' twice, it'll only animate the first time. You need to go 'down' again before it will animate 'up'. But you should be able to work out how to get it working now.